# Programming a run schedule

Tags: python, schedule

Currently I'm trying to add a seasonal run schedule to a current program that I have. I've come up with the following code bellow that works but I'm trying to do this without having to regularly update the year in my defined dates.

```
from datetime import date
td = date.today()

fs = date(2018, 3, 31)
fe = date(2018, 10, 18)
ws = date(2018, 5, 31)
we = date(2019, 3, 18)
sps = date(2018, 10, 1)
spe = date(2019, 5, 18)
sus = date(2018, 11, 1)
sue = date(2019, 9, 17)

if fs < td < fe:
    print "FALL"
if ws < td < we:
    print "WINTER"
if sps < td < spe:
    print "SPRING"
if sus < td < sue:
    print "SUMMER"
```

With the current code, if today were 10/5/18, it prints:

```
FALL
WINTER
SPRING
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Is your code working? What is it even supposed to do? Please add a sample output of what you want to get.

Comment: Ralf, the current code works. What it does is compare the date for today against the schedule that I defined and run the appropriate IF statements.  Since today is 10/5/18, the code will print FALL, WINTER, SPRING.  What I'm trying to do is auto update the year within the schedule after the season has passed so I don't have to manually update each year myself.  For example after the 10/18/18 date the year defined for FS and FE will change to 2019.

Comment: you may want to make the comparison between the `.day` and `.month` attributes of the date objects, instead of using the year. The information contained in the year is not really useful in your case, and you might as well initialise it to 1970 or anything else

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code is independent of the year (or am I missunderstanding your code??), so maybe you could just take the current year as the base.

```
from datetime import date

td = date.today()
current_year = td.year

fa_s = date(current_year    ,  3, 31)
fa_e = date(current_year    , 10, 18)
wi_s = date(current_year    ,  5, 31)
wi_e = date(current_year + 1,  3, 18)
sp_s = date(current_year    , 10,  1)
sp_e = date(current_year + 1,  5, 18)
su_s = date(current_year    , 11,  1)
su_e = date(current_year + 1,  9, 17)
```